# How to enable secure Corba/IIOP communication with Sun ORB or ORBD?

Tags: security, corba, iiop

I am creating a new CORBA client and registering this to the Persistent Naming Service which was started using Sun ORB or ORBD. I want to use secure IIOP communication for my application and I am able to set the security properties while starting my CORBA client as I am using jacorb API for client. For some reason I am using ORBD service(instead of any other ORB such as JacORB) and could not find a way to start the ORBD service in a secure way.

So I would like to know how to enforce a secure (encrypted) IIOP connection when I start ORBD service?
Does it expose some properties to be set to enforce security?

Thanks for any suggestions.